# how to call a j-query modal dialog in jsf dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jsf-2

I have jquery javascript file that calls modal this way, this is in the js script

```
$("#dialog_f").dialog({autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 400});

$("#dialog_p").click(function() {
    $("#dialog_f").dialog('open');
    console.log('modal called');
});
```

And this is in the jsf xhtml page

```
          <button class="btn" type="button" id="dialog_p">Update Fault</button>

          <div class="dialog" id="dialog_f" style="display: none;" title="Update Fault">                                
            <div class="block">


            </div>
          </div>
```

This works fine in a normal page but in a jsf dataTable i noticed it calls the last Object in the list from a managed bean and doesnt popup the modal. i noticed this by printing the console.log in the js file. is there a possibility that the id is been rendered in the list and the controller doesnt know which button is supposed to call the modal ?

```
   <ui:define name="content">


            <h:dataTable var="fau" value="#{faultController.allFaultsT}" >
                <h:column >
                    <f:facet name="header" >
                    Fault Id              
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value="#{fau.faultId}" />
                </h:column>

                 <h:column >
                     <f:facet name="header" >
                      action              
                    </f:facet>

                  <button class="btn" type="button" id="dialog_f">Update Fault</button>

         <div class="dialog" id="dialog_p" style="display: none;" title="Update Fault">                                
                        <div class="block">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable>


        </ui:define>
```

N.B Alternatively, using a class pops up the all the modals which is a bad idea ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got it to work by using specific id from var object , and all dialog still in the  so when rendered it generates the dialog in the  element.

```
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="openDialog('#{fau.faultId}');">Update Fault</button>

                    <div id="#{fau.faultId}" class="dialog" style="display: none;" title="Update Fault">                                
                        <div class="block">
                            <h:outputText value="#{fau.faultId}" />

                        </div>
                    </div>




 function openDialog(value) {


 $('#'+value).dialog({autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 400});     

 $('#'+value).dialog('open');
 console.log('modal called '+value);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dialog_p").dialog({autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 400});

function openDialog() {
    $("#dialog_p").dialog('open');
    console.log('modal called');
};

....

 <ui:define name="content">
    <h:dataTable var="fau" value="#{faultController.allFaultsT}" >
        <h:column >
            <f:facet name="header" >
            Fault Id              
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{fau.faultId}" />
        </h:column>
         <h:column>
             <f:facet name="header" >
              action              
            </f:facet>
          <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="openDialog();">Update Fault</button>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

    <div class="dialog" id="dialog_p" style="display: none;" title="Update Fault">                                
        <div class="block">
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:define>
```

Why do you need a dialog for each row in the table? I suppose you want to show the row specific data in the dialog. If so then you can achieve this through your backing bean.

Comment: Everything seems fine with the javascript but the modal dialog doesnt seem to pop-up, i can see the console.log been called.

Comment: @Johnson Eyo jsf may prepend its own id chain. You may use a class name if the dialog is outside of the table

Comment: thanks @multiSync, but the dialog needs to be in the table <h:column /> so i can get a reference from a var object in <h:table /> , i tried using class but class keeps popping all the dialogs in the list.

Comment: @Johnson Eyo It's a bad idea to create multiple dialogs. You may use your bean here: when button is clicked then the action is sent to the bean and set a required object. Then you update your dialog area and oncomplete you call the dialog opening. Everything can be done with ajax